# Array returns nothing with async and await in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am new to the node.js and I need to extract all the snapshot IDs by running the following function:

```
const createSnapshots = async volumes => {
  try {
    let arr = [];
    volumes.Volumes.map(async (vol, i) => {
      let volId = vol.VolumeId;
      let isEncrypted = vol.Encrypted;
      let tags = vol.Tags;
      console.log(i, volId, isEncrypted, tags);
      if (!isEncrypted && tags[0].Value === 'Test') {
        // console.log(volId);
        let params = {
          Description: 'test snapshot',
          VolumeId: volId
        };
        let snapshots = await ec2.createSnapshot(params).promise();
        let snapshotId = snapshots.SnapshotId;
        ec2.waitFor(
          'snapshotCompleted',
          (params = { 'snapshot-id': snapshotId })
        );
        arr.push({ snapshotId, tags });
        console.log(arr);
      }
    });
    console.log(arr);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

However, the array returns as empty. If I console log the array in the if statement, it returns data. I know there is something to deal with the promise. However, I have no idea where I have to modify the code. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is .map() function is async. Hence you should use an await. Then only you can get arr value outside of if. It should be something like that.

```
const createSnapshots = (volumes ) => {
const arr = volumes.Volumes.map(async (vol, i) => {
  let volId = vol.VolumeId;
  let isEncrypted = vol.Encrypted;
  let tags = vol.Tags;
  console.log(i, volId, isEncrypted, tags);
  if (!isEncrypted && tags[0].Value === 'Test') {
    // console.log(volId);
    let params = {
      Description: 'test snapshot',
      VolumeId: volId
    };
    let snapshots = await ec2.createSnapshot(params).promise();
    let snapshotId = snapshots.SnapshotId;
    ec2.waitFor(
      'snapshotCompleted',
      (params = { 'snapshot-id': snapshotId })
    );
    return {
        tags : tags,
        snapshotId : snapshotId 
    }
  }
 });
 return Promise.all(arr);
}
```

Through this way you will get return of your array.

Comment: This wording is a tiny bit confusing. `.map` is **not** async, but the callback being passed to it is. If OP is unfamiliar with async/await: The idea here is that the `.map` function *synchronously* returns a list of promises that will all complete sometime in the future. The `Promise.all()` at the end only resolves once every promise in the array has resolved. Since this returns a promise you'll have to `await` or `.then()` the result!

Comment: @bscotchAdam Gotcha, this async stuff really made me headache haha

Comment: @Akira Yep, took me eons before it became second nature. Incredibly useful and powerful once you get used it, though.